# How to Convert, in JS, an import statement to a require() statement

Tags: javascript, import, require

I have a Statement in JavaScript:

```
import app, { set } from '../app';
```

How can I write an equivalent statement in a form, such as I don't get an error like 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'.

I could convert similar less complex statement by using a format:
var Foo = require(foo);

but don't understand how to convert this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every `import` can be converted into a `require`. In pure Node.js this is only possible if the module being required is a CommonJS module, but the situation is different with tools such as Webpack or Babel.

I image you are using one of those tools, otherwise you would not be able to import `../app` without a file extension in the first place: you would need to import from `../app.js` or `../app/index.js` explicitly, or to use export mappings, but that's a different story.

Then if

```js
import app, { set } from '../app';
```

is a valid import in a ES module, with whatever loader, the equivalent CommonJS syntax would be

```js
const app = require('../app');
const { set } = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple one... If you break it down the first one is a default import , the second is the named import so if you wait to maintain the functionality you can either ..

```
const {set} = require('../app')   // is similar to a named import
```

```
const app = require ('./app') // is going to be similar to a default
```

```
require('../app') // will simply fire whenever it is called in the code.
```

the last one acts similar to

```
import * from "./..app"
```

this will destructure the exports and provide just the one you are using inside your brackets.

___ edit below just to add the other end for clarity

```
export default app = {...}
```

turns into

```
const app = {...}

module.exports = app
```

where as

```
export const app = {...}
export const anotherApp = {...}
```

turns into

```
const app ...
const anotherApp...

module.exports = {
  app, 
  anotherApp
}
```